# Redirection from "https://www" to "https://"

Tags: asp.net, redirect, ssl

We have the ASP.NET application hosted as Azure WebApp and configured the domain from GoDaddy. We bought SSL for non-www domain. We used the following redirection rule:

```
<rewrite> 
  <rules>
   <rule name="Redirect to Example.com">
    <match url="(.*)"/>
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!^Example.com)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://Example.com/{R:1}"/>
  </rule>

  <rule name="Redirect to https">
    <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
         <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
   </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Is there a way to add another rule to redirect request to "https://www" to "https://"?

Thanks,

Jay

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge with my Windows hosting since I have a wildcard cert and host a few subdomains.  Here's the web.config I put together, give it a shot and let me know!  It seems to work great for me, but my site is extremely simple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />

        <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="remove www" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.YourDomain\.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://YourDomain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```